# Shopping cart price rule Label not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, price, shopping-cart-price-rules

I made a price rule:

- if 2 items from category 44, then 50% discount.

The price rule works, but for some reason the price rule label is not showing in the frontend.

It might have been my old programmer who have removed it. So is there a place where I can check to see if it's the code that has been altered? - or am I simply misunderstanding the purpose of the price rule label?

Comment: does solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation here.  If it helps, v1.8 - this shopping cart rule is also working fine (if $75 or more, if not in HI, AK, etc., if ground shipping selected, then get free shipping), but as OP, the label is not displaying on the frontend. 
The label does show if any other shopping cart label is triggered and displayed, but it doesn't show if no other label or if only catalog labels and the like are triggered.